# Dataview Rowfilter

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview, dataview

I have a textbox and a button. What i am attempting to do is filter a gridview with the data that has been searched for. The two fields im searching for are customerID and CustomerName.

My code:

```
Dim GetAllCusts As New BusinessLayer.Customer
Dim dt As DataTable = GetAllCusts.GetCustomers 
Dim dv As New DataView(dt)

dv.RowFilter = String.Format("CustomerID='{0}' Or CustomerName='{0}'", SearchTextbox.Text) 

gridview1.DataSource = dv
gridview1.DataBind()
```

When searching for a customer id everything works. When searching for a customer name i get "Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Int32 and System.String.".

I tried to CONVERT(CustomerName, System.String) but that didnt resolve however i think this was leading me away from the initial problem as i started to guess around.

I would like to have one textbox to search for a customer id and customer name. What is wrong with the RowFilter and how could it be resolved?

Thanks

Comment: Why did someone downvote my question without an explanation after almost 4 years?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a conceptual problem. Or you search for a number or you search for a string.
I think you should change your code in this way

```
Dim custID as Integer
if Int32.TryParse(SearchTextbox.Text, custID) Then
   ' CustomerID is a numeric field - no need to use single quotes'
   dv.RowFilter = String.Format("CustomerID={0}", custID) 
else
   ' CustomerName is a string. Use single quotes and double the '
   ' possible single quotes inside the search box'
   dv.RowFilter = String.Format("CustomerName='{0}'", SearchTextbox.Text.Replace("'", "''") 
End If
gridview1.DataSource = dv
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I guess CutomerId is a integer field and when you try to search for a Name which is a string field you are trying to search an integer field with a string value.